# How to use nested paramter in SoapUI context.expand expression?

Tags: groovy, soapui

My use case is that I want to do a bulk update of request bodies in multiple SoapUI projects.

Example of request body.

```
{
 "name": "${#TestSuite#NameProperty}" 
 "id": "${#TestSuite#IdProperty}"
}
```

I want to expand the property ${#TestSuite#NameProperty} through Groovy, and get the value stored at TestSuite level then modify it as necessary.

Suppose I have 50 test steps in my test case and I want to expand the request for each one from Groovy script. To expand a specific test steps, I would pass the test Steps's name. For example:

```
expandedProperty = context.expand('${testStep1#Request}')
```

But, how can I achieve the same, if I wanted to iterate over all 50 test steps? I tried to used a nested parameter inside the context.expand expression, but it did not work. For Example:

```
currentTestStepName = "TestStep1"
expandedProperty = context.expand('${${currentTestStepName}#Request}')
```

This only returned me the expanded request from the test step right above it (where I am running the groovy script from) rather than the "TestStep1" step. ( Which is madness!)

Also, context.expand only seems to work while executing via Groovy script from the SoapUI workspace project. Is there and other way, or method similar to context.expand which can expand the properties like "${#TestSuite#NameProperty}" during headless execution? Eg: A groovy compiled jar file imported in SoapUI.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: One way I figured out to do it is by constructing a string that sums up to be the actual TestStep name, and it worked. But, I was hoping may be there was an easier way to do it. Example:      **string = "\$"+"{TestStep1#Request}"**   and then expand the string **context.expand(string)**

Comment: What is your use case? Just want write all the requests of the test to some where? Is groovy script in the same test case?

Comment: Updated my usecase in the original question.

Comment: can you check if the updated answer suits your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `context.expand('${${currentTestStepName}#Request}')` way to get it.

There are other approaches as well, which does not use context.expand.

*In order to get single test step request of any given test step:*

Here user passes step name to the variable `stepName`.

```
log.info context.testCase.testSteps[stepName].getPropertyValue('Request')
```

If you want to get all the requests of the test case, here is the simple way using the below script.

```
/**
 * This script loops thru the tests steps of SOAP Request steps,
 * Adds the step name, and request to a map.
 * So, that one can query the map to get the request using step name any time later.
 */
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep
def requestsMap = [:]
context.testCase.testStepList.each { step ->
    log.info "Looking into soap request step: ${step.name}"
    if (step instanceof WsdlTestRequestStep) {
        log.info "Found a request step of required type "
        requestsMap[step.name] = context.expand(step.getPropertyValue('Request'))
    }
}
log.info requestsMap['TestStep1']
```

**Update :**
If the step that you are interested is `REST` step, use below condition instead of `WsdlTestRequestStep` in the above.

```
if (step instanceof com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep) { //do the stuff }
```

Comment: I tried to use getPropertyValue('Request') but, it returns the actual string  as it it, including "${#TestSuite#NameProperty}". However, I want the actual value inside "${#TestSuite#NameProperty}", which is why I was trying to use context.expand.

Comment: Why do you want to replace the value `${#TestSuite#NameProperty}`, instead change the property value.

Comment: The bulk update utility I am working on, involves converting a JSON request to a new one which has different structure. Also, I cannot change the property, as I have some fulfillment conditions to check before I update the property.

Comment: Even the if `${#TestSuite#NameProperty}` is there in the request, it will any send the actual value when the request is sent, right?

Comment: @Dighate I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but adding `context.expand` to the request string using @Rao approach could do the trick: `requestsMap[step.name] = context.expand(step.getPropertyValue('Request'))`

Comment: @albciff, yes, that is a good catch of the change required if that is what author of the question is looking for. Of course, it is also possible to set the changed request into the step without even requiring to put into the map.

Comment: Updated the answer with @albciff comment, and it does not seem to have any side affects as well.

Comment: I owe thanks(Muchas gracias) to @albciff for his valuable input by forseeing authors problem. And glad that it helped.

Comment: de nada @Rao :)